# Swapping hard drives from a lenovo T430 to lenovo T440p

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

Is it possible to swap a HDD from a Lenovo T430 into a T440p without too much trouble? I'd like to keep both OSs intact.

Comment: Assuming they are both the same form factor, I don't see why not.

Comment: Yeah im trying it now with a cloned drive so far it seems to work fine I need to do a handful of driver updates still but other than that it works like magic.

Comment: Yes the hardware is different so you will have to update the drivers, but glad to hear it worked

Comment: On second thought I would not recommend that people do this. Even though it booted fine a few drivers refused to install. Besides that things explorer was bugging out hard. I ended up just installing a fresh version of windows 7.